# Does the zero random variable has a density function?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I have the following question:

> Does the random variable $0$ which is always zero has a density function?

I'm somehow thinking about this fact and I'm really insecure I mean one should be able to compute $\Bbb{P}(0\leq B)$ but this depends on the set B doesn't it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The density function would have to be $0$ , but then the integral over $\mathbb R$ would be $0$ instead of $1$. hence, there is no density function doing the job.

Comment: @Peter So would this mean that $\max(X,0)$ would have no density function for example. So $X$ is a random variable where I now assume that it has a density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mahdi noted, it didn't have a Lebesgue density. It has a mass function, or if you prefer its density is a distribution without a measure. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: So would this mean that $\max(X,0)$ would have no density function w.r.t. the lebesgue measure for example. So $X$ is a random variable where I now assume that it has a density

Comment: @Wave If $X$ has a density with P(X\ge0)>0, $\max(X,\,0)$ has what is called a mixed distribution, with a probability mass at $0$.

Comment: But I mean if $0$ does not have a density, how can I compute the mixed distribution? So I mean for independent random variables we know that if $W=\max(X,Y)$ then $F_W=F_X\cdot F_Y$ but then the density should be its derivative, but then $F_Y‘$ should be the density which doesn‘t work in our case if $Y=0$

Comment: @Wave It has $P(\max(X,\,0)=0)=P(X\ge0)$, regardless of whether $X$ can be $0$. But left of $0$, the distribution is the same as for $X$.

Comment: Sorry I added something in my last comment

Comment: So you did. I strongly advise you to ask a fresh question that asks about what you _actually_ wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

It does not have a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure. However, it has a density with respect to the counting measure, which is basically point mass with mass of one at zero.